# presentViewControler pushes all Controllers to stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

i have a tableView as my first view. every cell is clickable and on click, i used presentViewController to show current view with new data. i don't have navigation bar, so i cant use navigation controller and push. the problem is every time i click on a cell, it shows a new view (which is fine) but on pressing back button, it only moves back one step, but i want to make it go to first view. how can i do it?

```
print("clicked " + String(indexPath.row) )
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("playVideo") as! PlayVideoViewController

preferences.setValue( self.video[indexPath.row].id , forKey: "id" )
//self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
  self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

back:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: if you are using UINavigationController you can show 'vc' in navigation controller stack by pushing it with method -pushViewController:animated: and return back button will call -popToRootViewControllerAnimated: method of navigation controller.

Comment: @IgorBidiniuc i don't have navigationController, so i can't use it

Comment: so why you can't use it? you can hide navigation bar.

Comment: @IgorBidiniuc thanks,i didn't know i can hide nav bar.  i think i can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to the first VC use that code:

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```